# Using subprocess to run Python script on Windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

Is there a simple way to run a Python script on Windows/Linux/OS X?

On the latter two, `subprocess.Popen("/the/script.py")` works, but on Windows I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_functional.py", line 91, in test_functional
    log = tvnamerifiy(tmp)
  File "test_functional.py", line 49, in tvnamerifiy
    stdout = PIPE
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 804, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

---

> *[monkut's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24718/monkut) comment*: The use case isn't clear. Why use subprocess to run a python script? Is there something preventing you from importing the script and calling the necessary function?

I was writing a quick script to test the overall functionality of a Python-command-line tool (to test it on various platforms). Basically it had to create a bunch of files in a temp folder, run the script on this and check the files were renamed correctly.

I could have imported the script and called the function, but since it relies on `sys.argv` and uses `sys.exit()`, I would have needed to do something like..

```
import sys
import tvnamer
sys.argv.append("-b", "/the/folder")
try:
    tvnamer.main()
except BaseException, errormsg:
    print type(errormsg)
```

Also, I wanted to capture the stdout and stderr for debugging incase something went wrong.

Of course a better way would be to write the script in more unit-testable way, but the script is basically "done" and I'm doing a final batch of testing before doing a "1.0" release (after which I'm going to do a rewrite/restructure, which will be far tidier and more testable)

Basically, it was much easier to simply run the script as a process, after finding the `sys.executable` variable. I would have written it as a shell-script, but that wouldn't have been cross-platform. The final script can be found [here](http://github.com/dbr/tvdb_api/blob/c8d7b356cd1a7bb2ab22b510ea74e03a7d27fad6/tests/test_functional.py)

Comment: The use case isn't clear.  Why use subprocess to run a python script?  Is there something preventing you from importing the script and calling the necessary function?

Comment: Had the same problem when running nodejs modules from python. subprocess.call([r'..\nodejs\npm'], shell=True) solved the problem.

Comment: I don't think you need to defend the fact that this isn't a unit test. I would call it an acceptance test since it validates that the script behaves as users need it to independently of its implementation which is a perfectly healthy test to write.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Just found [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.executable) - the full path to the current Python executable, which can be used to run the script (instead of relying on the shbang, which obviously doesn't work on Windows)

```
import sys
import subprocess

theproc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "myscript.py"])
theproc.communicate()
```

Comment: you could use `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "myscript.py"])` instead.

Comment: Or better yet, in Python 3.5+, use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run): `subprocess.run([sys.executable, 'myscript.py'], check=True)`

Answer (score 26):

How about this:

```
import sys
import subprocess

theproc = subprocess.Popen("myscript.py", shell = True)
theproc.communicate()                   # ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This tells `subprocess` to use the OS shell to open your script, and works on anything that you can just run in cmd.exe.

Additionally, this will search the PATH for "myscript.py" - which could be desirable.

Comment: I think that'll function the same, if I recall right shell=True just stops subprocess from escaping any special characters (so "mycmd > somefile.txt" redirects text to somefile.txt, rather than trying to execute a file called "mycmd > somefile.txt")

Comment: Here's a situation in which the two are significantly different. Suppose "myscript.py" is in the system PATH, and not in the current directory. If you use "shell = True" the script will be found on the PATH, but if you use "sys.executable" it won't.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean (although the script I was trying to run was always going to be in the current directory)

Comment: Fixed my error, by the way it works without shell = True on python3 and fails randonly on 2.7, don't know why.

Answer (score 7):

Yes `subprocess.Popen(cmd, ..., shell=True)` works like a charm.  On Windows the `.py` file extension is recognized, so Python is invoked to process it (on *NIX just the usual shebang).  The path environment controls whether things are seen.  So the first arg to `Popen` is *just the name of the script*.

```
subprocess.Popen(['myscript.py', 'arg1', ...], ..., shell=True)
```

Comment: `shell=True # do not show the command prompt then true, if false show it`

Answer (score 5):

It looks like windows tries to run the script using its own EXE framework rather than call it like

```
python /the/script.py
```

Try,

```
subprocess.Popen(["python", "/the/script.py"])
```

Edit: "python" would need to be on your path.

Comment: The python.org Windows installer doesn't seem to put the "python" command in PATH, and I think it would have the .exe suffix (which would break the other platforms)

Comment: Hm, it seems you can exclude the .exe on Windows as long as it's in PATH, but you have to manually add Python to it

Comment: So use "cmd /S /C" instead of "python" - it's always on the path and will run the script so long as the extension is registered.

Answer (score 3):

For example, to execute following with command prompt or BATCH file we can use this:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program files(x86)\dev_appserver.py" --host 0.0.0.0 --post 8080 "C:\blabla\"
```

Same thing to do with Python, we can do this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['C:/Python27/python.exe', 'C:\\Program files(x86)\\dev_appserver.py', '--host', '0.0.0.0', '--port', '8080', 'C:\\blabla'], shell=True)
```

or

```
subprocess.Popen(['C:/Python27/python.exe', 'C:/Program files(x86)/dev_appserver.py', '--host', '0.0.0.0', '--port', '8080', 'C:/blabla'], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a pathname separator which is platform dependent. Windows uses "\" and Unix uses "/".

Comment: Good point, although in the actual script that caused the error I used os.path.join() (although I should have mentioned that)

Comment: Of course the forward slash has been valid on Windows since prehistoric times and still is, so that's not a problem.

Comment: @romkyns not really: subprocess.call([r'..\nodejs\npm'], shell=True) works, while subprocess.call(['../nodejs/npm'], shell=True) gives '..' is not recognized as internal or external command

Comment: @Stefan, that would be the shell complaining and not the underlying Windows API.

Answer (score 1):

When you are running a python script on windows in subprocess you should use python in front of the script name.  Try:

```
process = subprocess.Popen("python /the/script.py")
```

Answer (score 0):

*Supplemental info*: It is worth noting that the documentation states that you need to use `shell=True` if you are using a dos shell command like `dir`

without it you get something like this.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run(['dir'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __ini
t__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _exe
cute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>>> subprocess.run(['dir'], shell=True)
 Volume in drive J is garbage
 Volume Serial Number is 5EE7-B084
```

Also you can use path like objects for the args which is recent addition.

```
from pathlib import Path 
subprocess.run(Path('c:/proj/myfile.bat'))
```

Also worth noting there is a whole set of [windows specific controls](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#windows-popen-helpers) that allow you to control how a process is spawned which concurrent operations can use.

So controlling subprocesses on windows is not as simple as posix style.