# How to pass argument to cmd.exe in from python script?

Tags: python, subprocess, command-line-arguments, cmd

I want to be able to run cmd.exe from a Python script and a particular command with arguments but I can't seem to get it working.

I have tried

```
cmdL = r"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
schTasks = "schtasks.exe"
#run the schtasks.exe
os.system(cmdL + schTasks)
```

but the dos window appears and then disappears quickly.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it should stick around?

Comment: You should be using the `subprocess` module.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/912847/1224443

Comment: I don't know much about windows, but it seems like there should be a space between `cmd.exe` and `schtasks.exe`.  Also, you should probably look into `subprocess`.

Comment: because when I only add the cmdL variable to os.system, it doesnt disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modern way of executing processes from a Python script is by using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["schtasks.exe"])
```

You can also pass arguments, for example:

```
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

This means you won't need to utilize `cmd.exe`. Python will execute the given executable with the given parameters as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You forget the space between `cmd.exe` and the argument.

```
os.system("%s %s" % (cmdL, schTasks))
```

Nonetheless is the better way to go via `subprocess` like the other answer.