# Get Exceptions from popen in python

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I executed this code in python: (test.py)

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("file.bat").wait()
```

Here is file.bat:

```
@echo off
start c:\python27\python.exe C:\Test\p1.py %*
start c:\python27\python.exe C:\Test\p2.py %*
pause
```

Here is p1.py:

```
This line is error
print "Hello word"
```

p2.py is not interesting

I want to know the exception(not only compiling error) in p1.py by running test.py?
How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it working:
`test.py`

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen(["./file.sh"]).wait()
```

Make sure to add the `[]` around file, as well as the `./`. You can also add arguments, like so:
`["./file.sh", "someArg"]`
Note that I am not on Windows, but this fixed it on Ubuntu. Please comment if you are still having issues

EDIT:
I think the real solution is: [Using subprocess to run Python script on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912830/using-subprocess-to-run-python-script-on-windows)

This way you can run a python script from python, while still using Popen

Comment: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
-I got this error

Comment: why file.sh? my file is .bat

Comment: I am on linux, and mine cannot run `bat`. Just replace `sh` with `bat` and try it.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912830/using-subprocess-to-run-python-script-on-windows