# run cmd.exe commands and more things

Tags: python, shell, download, rename

Hi I want create a python script that executes a command line cmd.exe with echo off and with this comand below

unrar.exe -e -w -b compression.rar c:/tmp

notepad.exe readdocument.txt

and then after this command line must close the command line , and must execute a normal python script , which is this one below

```
os.rename('readdocument.txt','readdocument-done.txt')
import urllib

testfile = urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve("http://randomsite.com/file.gz", "file.gz")
```

how can I create this script correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: If you have `echo off`, why run `cmd.exe`?  What's wrong with just running the programs one after the other from Python?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a windows execution environment and what you are possibly looking for is:

1. A batch script:

   Quick intro: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/index.htm
2. Or Powershell script:

   https://blog.udemy.com/powershell-tutorial/
3. Alternatively, you may use Python's subprocess module to execute native commands:

   [Using subprocess to run Python script on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912830/using-subprocess-to-run-python-script-on-windows)

Comment: I want to use only python

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to redirect the output to `stdout`? if so, you can do this by using:

```
subprocess.call(['commands','here']) 

import subprocess                                               
subprocess.call(['unrar', 'e', 'w', 'b', 'compression.rar', 
                             'c:/tmp'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It will return 0 if successful else 1.