# Python Subprocess.Run not running Inkscape pdf to svg

Tags: python, subprocess, inkscape

I am using Inkscape to take an input single page pdf file and to output an svg file.  The following works from the command line

`c:\progra~1\Inkscape\inkscape -z -f "N:\pdf_skunkworks\inflation-report-may-2018-page0.pdf" -l "N:\pdf_skunkworks\inflation-report-may-2018-page0.svg"`

where `-z` is short for `--without-gui`, `-f` is short for input file, `-l` is short for `--export-plain-svg`.  And that works from command line.

I could not get the equivalent to work from Python, either passing the command line as one long string or as separate arguments.  `stderr` and `stdout` give no error as they both print `None`

```
import subprocess #import call,subprocess
#completed = subprocess.run(["c:\Progra~1\Inkscape\Inkscape.exe",r"-z -f \"N:\pdf_skunkworks\inflation-report-may-2018-page0.pdf\" -l \"N:\pdf_skunkworks\inflation-report-may-2018-page0.svg\""])
completed = subprocess.run(["c:\Progra~1\Inkscape\Inkscape.exe","-z", r"-f \"N:\pdf_skunkworks\inflation-report-may-2018-page0.pdf\"" , r"-l \"N:\pdf_skunkworks\inflation-report-may-2018-page0.svg\""])
print ("stderr:" + str(completed.stderr))
print ("stdout:" + str(completed.stdout))
```

Just to test OS plumbing I wrote some VBA code (my normal language) and this works

```
Sub TestShellToInkscape()
    '* Tools->References->Windows Script Host Object Model (IWshRuntimeLibrary)
    Dim sCmd As String
    sCmd = "c:\progra~1\Inkscape\inkscape -z -f ""N:\pdf_skunkworks\inflation-report-may-2018-page0.pdf"" -l ""N:\pdf_skunkworks\inflation-report-may-2018-page0.svg"""
    Debug.Print sCmd

    Dim oWshShell As IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell
    Set oWshShell = New IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell

    Dim lProc As Long
    lProc = oWshShell.Run(sCmd, 0, True)

End Sub
```

So I'm obviously doing something silly in the Python code.  I'm sure experienced Python programmer could solve easily.

Comment: it's possible your process is not even running, no exception is being surfaced? can you try `Popen` and `communicate`? like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912830/using-subprocess-to-run-python-script-on-windows)

Comment: @Srini: thanks for feedback.  Thanks to you I ran SysInternals Process Monitor to check the "spawn stack".  This helped me diagnose the command line and along with JacobIRR's suggestion helped me solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap your slashes:

```
import subprocess #import call,subprocess
completed = subprocess.run(['c:/Progra~1/Inkscape/Inkscape.exe',
      '-z', 
      '-f', r'N:/pdf_skunkworks/inflation-report-may-2018-page0.pdf' , 
      '-l', r'N:/pdf_skunkworks/inflation-report-may-2018-page0.svg'])
print ("stderr:" + str(completed.stderr))
print ("stdout:" + str(completed.stdout))
```

Python knows to swap forward slashes for back slashes on windows OS, and your back slashes are currently acting as escape prefixes.

Comment: You put me on the right track, I've pasted working code into this answer.  Thanks.